# Composer error in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I installed Laravel 4 and Composer yesterday to get started with laravel. I was following this guide http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-uber-quick-start-with-auth-guide and everything went well.

Today however when I tried to make my own laravel project by running

> composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject"

in the terminal, I receive this message

> ?????????%

I have also tried cd to the project I made yesterday and ran

> composer install

but again I get the same ???????%.

Has anybody experienced this problem before?

I am on Mac 10.8.4 and running PHP 5.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you skip `Step 2` from that url and

try

`php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel myproject` see if this error re-occurs?

Comment: I get the
"Could not open input file: composer.phar"
message

Comment: did you run Step 1? Since you previously did Step 2, the composer.phar would have moved. You will need to re-install composer using Step 1

Comment: Yes, I get ... #!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The detect_unicode setting must be disabled.
Add the following to the end of your `php.ini`:
    detect_unicode = Off

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: /usr/local/etc/php/5.3/php.ini
If you can not modify the ini file, you can also run `php -d option=value` to modify ini values on the fly. You can use -d multiple times.

Comment: Oh okay, so I followed the terminal. I guess I have to install composer for each new project I do? I thought I had installed it globally. Okay thank you!

Comment: You can install it globally, but you will have to ensure that the composer is up to date every time you create a new project, installing it everytime will ensure that you are using the latest version of composer.